# C++17, deprecated functions in <memory> standard library?

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer, c++17, c++20

I am just realizing that some functions of the [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) standard library have been **deprecated in C++17**. An example is [get_temporary_buffer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer):

```
template< class T >
std::pair< T*, std::ptrdiff_t > get_temporary_buffer( std::ptrdiff_t count );
```

Can somebody explain why? Can I expect there to be an alternative in C++20?

Comment: It has never been widely used, implementations usually just allocate chunk of memory using `operator new`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought it was some kind of optimized memory pool for small buffers.

Comment: AFAIK it's often used to implement `std::inplace_merge` which might use any allocated memory, even if it doesn't have as much memory as asked: the more memory, the faster, but even without memory the algorithm still works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the proposal that deprecates it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0.html#3.3):

> This API would be considered an incomplete thought were it proposed today. As a functional API it lacks exception safety if the function allocating the buffer leaks, yet we offer no RAII-like wrappers to promote safe use.
>
> It has been suggested that all current implementation of this API actually do not perform a more efficient allocation than the regular `new` operator, and, if that is genuinely the case, we should seriously consider deprecating this facility. Otherwise, we should probably complete the design with an appropriate guard/wrapper class, and encourage vendors to deliver on missed optimization opportunities.

In short, just use `new`/`delete`. Or your own temporary memory allocator; whichever works best for your needs.